# Alphanumeric sorting is not appearing for non-English languages

Tags: javascript, sorting

Currently I'm using this logic to get the alphanumeric sorting which must be applicable for both English and non-English languages. But this is not working for non-English languages.

```
alphanumericSortedValues.sort((a, b) => {
    var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
    return collator.compare(a, b);
});
```

And if I replace this with

```
const locale = Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getLanguageId();
alphanumericSortedValues.sort((a, b) => {
    var collator = new Intl.Collator(locale, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
    return collator.compare(a, b);
});
```

I'm facing some error in my browser console like

```
Uncaught RangeError: Incorrect locale information provided
```

Comment: What does `Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getLanguageId();`? The name and the error suggest it's not a valid locale.

Comment: This is how I'm getting locale, Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getLanguageId() is being used to obtain the preferred language setting of the user. This setting is based on the user's profile or browser settings and determines the language in which the content of the application should be presented to the user.

Comment: But *what does it give you*? It's *some sort* of locale information but *what kind of locale information*? Seems like it doesn't match the locale format required by `Intl.Collator` - this much I can tell you. I just cannot guess what format it supplies.

Comment: it gives the locale and language info like en_US,fr_CA etc

Comment: `en_US` is syntactically invalid: thus you get the `RangeError`. The expected format is `en-US` (note the hyphen instead of the underscore) as specified in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument)

Comment: what else  can I use instead of this?